# Access 2013/2016 does not support treeview control, giving error message "User defined type not defined"

Tags: vba, vb6, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a VBA project which runs perfectly upto windows 7 (both 32,64 bit) and upto office 2010. But when i try to run it on office 2013 or 2016. It does not load treeview control and gives error at:

Private SelectedNode As MSComctlLib.node

The things i have already tried are:

1. Followed this post thoroughly
   http://thesmileycoder.com/treeview-working-in-access2013/
2. Re-registered MSCOMCTL.OCX/MSCOMCT2.OCX several times on both SYSTEM32 and SYSWOW64 folders.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Office?

Comment: @ThunderFrame, i am using 64 bit office 2013/2016.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for clarifying that you're using Office 64-bit.

You should see this [article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-ca3253e5-ac01-4242-8a64-b56111a6f32d)

Specifically the section:

> Most things included in the 32-bit version of Office are included in the 64-bit version of Office.
>
> The following are some things not in the 64-bit version of Office.
>
> **ActiveX controls library, ComCtl** - This library contains ActiveX controls used to build solutions. It is most commonly used in Microsoft Access, Microsoft Excel, and Microsoft Word.
>
> SharePoint List control    The list view in SharePoint Technology isn’t available in 64-bit version of Office.

Followed by:

> **ActiveX controls library, ComCtl** - Any solutions using these controls don’t work. No good alternatives are available for some of these controls.

**EDIT**
And this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for 2010 spells it out in more detail:

> Native 64-bit processes in Office 2010 cannot load 32-bit binaries. This includes the common controls of MSComCtl (TabStrip, Toolbar, StatusBar, ProgressBar, **TreeView**, ListViews, ImageList, Slider, ImageComboBox) and the controls of MSComCt2 (Animation, UpDown, MonthView, DateTimePicker, FlatScrollBar).These controls were installed by previous versions of Microsoft Office and are installed by 32-bit Office 2010. An alternative must be found for existing Microsoft Office VBA solutions that utilize these controls when the code is migrated to 64-bit Office 2010. 64-bit Office 2010 does not provide 64-bit versions of the Common Controls.

Comment: thanks for this, Appreciated... although this forces me to install 32 bit version and then check.

Comment: that's really a dig at office, thanks. I have arranged office 32 bit. will let you know if it works in that.