# MSCOMCT2.OCX registers successfully but not listed in the additional controls

Tags: excel, vba

I have installed a DateTimePicker control and registered it. But is not listed in the additional controls. How can i solve this?
I am using Ms Office Home and Bussines 2016 64-bit.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612367/access-2013-2016-does-not-support-treeview-control-giving-error-message-user-d/37614882#37614882

Comment: This is exactly the reason why you should not be using it :) You may want to see [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 1):

MSCOMCT2.OCX will not work with 64-bit office.  You must uninstall and re-install with 32 bit version and that will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33402863)